# Function on power set: Negativity implication leads to monotonicity

Tags: order-theory, monotone-functions

so I have a binary function $f: P \times P \to \mathbb{R}$ over some power set $P$. I also have a partial ordering $(P,≤)$ over $P$ (by set size). For this function I know that

$f(a,b) ≥ 0 \implies f(a',b) ≥ 0 \quad \forall  a,a',b \in P \quad \text{and} \quad a ≤ a'$

What other conditions does $f$ need to satisfy in order for it to be a monotone over the partial order in the first argument?

Cheers, Paul

Comment: What do you mean by "set size"? What is the definition of $a\le b$?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the cardinality of the subsets of the set $S$ whose power set is $P \equiv 2^S$ to which the elements of $P$ stand in a one-to-one correspondence. So the partial order is defined such that $a < b$ iff $s(a) \subset s(b)$, where $s(\cdot)$ is the structure preserving function that maps elements of the power set into subsets of $S$. I didn't add that because I didn't think it was required for an answer. Sorry